# Could we ever kill 2 schodinger's cats?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, schroedingers-cat

In the following setup I'll be testing entanglement with 2 cats, namely Mew0 and Mew1 both are positioned exactly a light year away from each other. 2 identical bombs will be strapped to each cat and they will be confined to their respective boxes, you get the idea.

Now things are starting to get serious... within the next minute there is exactly a 50% chance that the bomb will explode hence killing the adjacent cat, for now please treat the bombs as entangled particles. Can I safely say that if I were to observe one of the bombs at that moment in time **ONLY 1** cat will die but never both?

I also setup a control without entangle the particles (bombs), results vary but there will be an equal probability that both cats are alive or dead.

Comment: **Can I safely say that if I were to observe one of the bombs at that moment in time ONLY 1 cat will die but never both?**  Of course not.  What if the entangled state is $A\otimes A+D\otimes D$ where $A$ yields a live cat and $D$ yields a dead one?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. How are the bombs entangled? Specifically, what does the state where bomb 0 explodes force the state of bomb 1 to be?

Comment: what do you guys mean? the bomb can only be in 2 states, it either explodes or not hence the cat will be killed or spared.

Comment: They're asking WHAT the entanglement is. Such as a restriction that only, but necessarily, one cat dies with each measurement.

Answer (score 1):

No, the bombs (plural) can be in any entangled state (singular), and there are much more than two. The outcome of measurement of the whole system will be either (alive,alive), (alive,dead), (dead,alive), or (dead,dead) and the entanglement can be set up so that these four possibilities have arbitrary probabilities (except that of course they must all add up to one). We can call these probabilities $p_{AA},$ $p_{AD},$ $p_{DA}$ and $p_{DD}$ where $p_{AA}+p_{AD}+p_{DA}+p_{DD}=1.$

If you make the additional requirement that each cat has a $50\%$ chance of survival then you know that $$ p_{AA}+p_{AD} = 1/2\\p_{AA}+p_{DA} = 1/2$$ since the first line is the probability the first cat survives and the second is the probability the second does.

You now have four unknowns and three variables, so there are infinitely many possibilities. For instance it could be, as you suggested, that $p_{AD}=p_{DA}=1/2$ and $p_{AA}=p_{DD}=0.$ In this case, either one cat dies or the other, never neither or both.

Or, it could be, as a commenter suggested, that $p_{AA}=p_{DD} = 1/2$ and $p_{AD}=p_{DA}=0.$ In this second case, either both cats die or neither do, never just one.

Both of these are valid solutions to the above system.

Your first case would be called "correlation $-1$" and the commenter's alternative is "correlation $+1$." But there are infinitely many other possibilities where the correlation can be anything between $-1$ and $+1.$

Comment: I thought QM removed (alive, alive) and (dead, dead) so that the outcome of the waveform is either (alive, dead) and (dead, alive). Meaning an act of observation will immediately collapse the wave function resulting in one cat being alive and the other guaranteed to  be dead. Am I right?

Comment: @user6760 No, you are not right. QM makes no such restriction, as I detailed in my answer. Measurement does indeed "collapse the wavefunction" but it can collapse to any of the four possible outcomes.

Comment: sorry I simply cannot understand why P(AD) and P(DA) is one of the possible outcome after I made the observation? I thought the wave function had collapsed by then... I still don't know how QM works :)

Comment: Yeah, I don't follow. I thought (A,D) and (D,A) were the ones you thought *were* allowed. Dead and alive are just labels. Instead let's do real physics and talk about spin up and spin down (also just labels, but less distracting ones.) The usual example of entanglement is that the measurement of spin up for particle one forces spin down in the other (and down forces up). What's conceptually wrong if instead the measurement of spin up forces spin up in the other (and down forces down)? Answer: absolutely nothing. Both are valid entangled states. Now replace up with 'alive' and down with 'dead'.